# When does node-mysql return `fields` as part of a query result

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

According to the [node-mysql documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries), the callback to a query will get three parameters - an error, the row(s) or result of the query, and something called `fields` which may or may not be passed everytime.

> fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)

I recently ran into a bug which resulted from node-mysql returning `fields` in my production environment, but not in my staging environment. I was using `async.auto` and passed the step callback directly to `mysql.query`. In production, `async.auto` combined `rows` and `fields` into an `arguments` array, which lead to that part of the service breaking down because it got data in an unexpected format.

I could not get my staging environment to have `fields` be passed to the callback, and when I tried locally I could not get `mysql` to not pass `fields`. Is there any way to know when `fields` will be passed by `mysql.query` and when will it not?

Essentially

```
async.auto({
  runQuery: (next) => {
    mysql.query(sql, values, next);
  }
},
(err, results) => {
  // if `fields` is not passed to the callback by mysql.query,
  // then results.runQuery will be a row, or an array of rows -
  // [
  //   [
  //   [
  //     {
  //       "columnValue": 1
  //     }
  //   ],
  //   [
  //     {
  //       "columnValue": 1
  //     }
  //   ]
  // ]
  // 
  // instead, if `fields` is passed to the callback by mysql.query,
  // then results.queryQuery will be an array containing the row(s)
  // and the fields
  // 
  // [
  //   [
  //     [
  //       {
  //         "columnValue": 1
  //       }
  //     ],
  //     [
  //       {
  //         "columnValue": 1
  //       }
  //     ]
  //   ],
  //   [
  //     [
  //       {
  //         "catalog": "def",
  //         "db": "",
  //         "table": "",
  //         "orgTable": "",
  //         "name": "columnValue",
  //         "orgName": "",
  //         "charsetNr": 63,
  //         "length": 21,
  //         "type": 8,
  //         "flags": 129,
  //         "decimals": 0,
  //         "zeroFill": false,
  //         "protocol41": true
  //       }
  //     ],
  //     [
  //       {
  //         "catalog": "def",
  //         "db": "",
  //         "table": "",
  //         "orgTable": "",
  //         "name": "columnValue",
  //         "orgName": "",
  //         "charsetNr": 63,
  //         "length": 21,
  //         "type": 8,
  //         "flags": 129,
  //         "decimals": 0,
  //         "zeroFill": false,
  //         "protocol41": true
  //       }
  //     ]
  //   ]
  // ]
});
```